# match subfolder name with file name and output folder python

Tags: python, directory

I have the following folder-file structure:

- mainfolder_segment_polygon

  - folder_poly5numSeg

    - subfolder_compactness40

      - subfolder_aoi1

        - file_aoi1_seg0.shp
        - file_aoi1_seg1.shp
      - subfolder_aoi2

        - file_aoi2_seg0.shp
        - file_aoi2_seg1.shp
  - folder_poly6numSeg

    - subfolder_compactness40

      - subfolder_aoi1

        - file_aoi1_seg0.shp
        - file_aoi1_seg1.shp
      - subfolder_aoi2

        - file_aoi2_seg0.shp
        - file_aoi2_seg1.shp

I want to be able to load all the files from the same folder (segment_polygon), apply a function to them, and export to another set of folders (segment_multipoly) with the same structure.

- The files from `r".\segmentation_aoi\segment_polygon\poly5numSeg\compactness40\aoi1"` should be processed together and be exported to `r".\segmentation_aoi\segment_multipoly\multi5numSeg\compactness40\aoi1"`
- The files from `r".\segmentation_aoi\segment_polygon\poly6numSeg\compactness40\aoi2"` should be processed together and be exported to `r".\segmentation_aoi\segment_multipoly\multi6numSeg\compactness40\aoi2"`

and so on...

The names "mainfolder", "folder", "subfolder", "file" are there just to indicate to which level the names belong, but they are not part of the folder's labels.

```
input_path = os.path.join(src, "segment_polygon\\")
output_path = os.path.join(src, "segment_multipoly\\")

root = Path(input_path)

for maindir, subdirs, shpfiles in os.walk(input_path):
    for shp in shpfiles:
        aoi_root, shp_ext = shp.split("_")
        for file in root.glob("*/*/*/*.shp"):
            part_path = Path(file).parts
            folder_numSeg_name = part_path[9] #here I get the subfolder "poly5numSeg", "poly6numSeg", etc
            folder_aoi_name = part_path[11] #here I get the subfolder "aoi1", "aoi2", etc...
            aoiprep_seg = part_path[12] # here I get the name of the file "aoi1_seg0.shp", aoi1_seg1.shp", etc
            if aoi_root == folder_aoi_name:
                '''apply a function to shp'''
                shp.to_file(os.path.join(output_path, folder_numSeg_name, "compactness40\\", folder_aoi_name, shp)
```

I am a bit at lost.
Working in Windows 10, Python 3. Thank you for all help.

UPDATE OF THE SCRIPT

```
segment_polygon = os.path.join(output, "segment_polygon\\") # input path
segment_multipoly = os.path.join(output, "segment_multipoly\\") # output path

# 1. get aoi directories
aoi_dir = [path for path in glob.glob(os.path.join(segment_polygon, "*/*/*"))
           if os.path.isdir(path)]

# list to store the shapefiles to be intersected
input_list = []

for path in aoi_dir:
    # 2. get the files
    shp_paths = glob.glob(path + os.sep + '*.shp')
    for shp_path in shp_paths:
        # 3. do things with shp_path
        full_path, seg_shp = os.path.split(shp_path)
        aoi_folder = full_path[-5:] # aoi01, aoi02, aoi03....aoi25
        if seg_shp.startswith(aoi_folder):
            input_list.append(shp_path) # creates the new list with shapefiles that start with the same aoiX value
        auto_inter = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(input_list[0]) #process shp
        for i in range(len(input_list)-1):
            mp = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(input_list[i+1]) # process shp
            auto_inter = gpd.overlay(auto_inter, mp, how='intersection') #process shp
        print(f"shp included in the list:\n {input_list}")
            # 4. create your output file path
        print(full_path)
        output_path = full_path.replace("poly", "multi")
        N_output_path = output_path.replace("gon", "polygon")
        print(f"output_path:\n {N_output_path}")
        # make sure the directories exist
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(N_output_path)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(N_output_path), exist_ok=True)
            # create output file name
            multipoly_name = aoi_folder + ".shp"
            # export
            auto_inter.to_file(os.path.join(N_output_path, multipoly_name)) #export shp
```

Incorporated changes from ygorg. However, it takes ALL the shapefiles for intersection. I want only aoi1 files for intersection and save on aoi1 folder. Then, aoi2 shapefiles and save on aoi2 folder, and so on. This doesn't work yet.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing `os.walk` and `glob` seem to be quite confusing. If you want to process each `aoiX` folder. Try to first list all those directories, then list the `.shp` files in each directory, then apply the function and finally create your output_path and write to it.

When working with files it's always good to decompose what you need to not get overwhelmed.

```
# 1. get aoi directories
aoi_dir = [path for path in glob.glob('segment_polygon/*/*/*')
           if os.path.isdir(path)]
for path in aoi_dir:
    # 2. get the files
    shp_paths = glob.glob(path + os.sep + '*.shp')
    for shp_path in shp_paths:
        # 3. do things with shp_path
        # 4. create your output file path
        output_path = shp_path.replace('segment_polygon', 'segment_multipoly')
        # make sure the directories exist
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(output_path), exist_ok=True)
        # write in output file
```

And always do a dry run without processing or writing anything, and printing the paths so you are sure of what goes where !

Comment: thank you! that helps with one part of the problem. However, I need to be able to only process all the aoi*_seg*.shp   files together that belong to the SAME aoi*.   The function I apply to them is an intersection. I need to intersect only all aoi1_*.shp   together and export them in the aoi1 folder. Then, all aoi2_*.shp  together, and export them in the aoi2 folder, and so on.

Comment: I think, it is os.makedirs, not os.path.makedirs

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. Thank you ygorg for the input. It led me to the right path.

```
# Create a list of the subfolders of segment_polygon
poly_dir = [path for path in glob.glob(os.path.join(segment_polygon, "*/*/*"))
       if os.path.isdir(path)]

for aoi_poly in poly_dir:

    # define input folder
    input_subfolder = aoi_poly.split("segment_polygon\\")[1] # splits the path at "...\\" and keeps the tail (position:1)
    #print(f"input folder: {input_subfolder}")

    #define export folder
    export_subfolder = input_subfolder.replace("poly", "multi")
    export_folder = os.path.join(segment_multipoly, export_subfolder)
    #print(f"output folder: {export_folder}")

    # define name output shapefile
    numseg, compactness, aoi = [int(s) for s in re.findall(r'\d+', aoi_poly)] #extract only the integers from the "poly" path
    name_output = "aoi" + str(aoi)+ "_" + "numSeg"+ str(numseg) + "_c" + str(compactness) + ".shp" # str() is used to concatenate integers as part of the string
    #print(f"shapefile label: {name_output}")

    full_outputpath = os.path.join(export_folder, name_output)
    #print(f"full output path: {full_outputpath}")

    # intersect and merge all single polygons
    input_list = list(filter(lambda mpoly: mpoly.endswith('.shp'), os.listdir(aoi_poly)))

     ###### apply my function here ######

    # export
    filetoexport.to_file(full_outputpath)
```